# Converting Gradle/IDEA project into multiple subprojects

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, gradle

I have an [IntelliJ IDEA (Community Edition 2016.2) project](https://github.com/hotmeatballsoup/intellij-scala-gradle-example) that was created by importing a file system project that had a `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle` defined inside its root. When I open it in IDEA everything is working nicely.

As you can see on GitHub, the basic project directory structure is currently:

```
intellij-scala-gradle-example/
    src/
      main/
          scala/
          resources/
      test/
          scala/
          resources/
    build.gradle
    settings.gradle
```

I now want to convert this project into 3 smaller subprojects so that the project directory structure *something* like:

```
intellij-scala-gradle-example/
    client/
        src/
          main/
              scala/
              resources/
          test/
              scala/
              resources/
    shared/
        src/
          main/
              scala/
              resources/
          test/
              scala/
              resources/
    server/
        src/
          main/
              scala/
              resources/
          test/
              scala/
              resources/
    build.gradle
    settings.gradle
```

I can handle running all the `mkdir`s on the command-line and physically restructuring the directories on the file system, but I'm not sure:

- What I need to do so that Gradle understands that I now have these 3 `client/`, `shared/` and `server/` sub-projects; and
- I'm not sure what I need to do so that IDEA picks up all of these changes and compiles things correctly

Obviously, any classes (under `shared/src/main/scala`) or resources (under `shared/src/main/resources`) in the "shared" project should be visible to `client/` and `server/`. But the client should never be able to "see" server classes/resources and vice versa.

**Any idea (no pun intended) how I could accomplish this, and what the order of events are here?**

---

**Update:** This screenshot shows the subprojects added to the project but IDEA not seeing them as Scala subprojects (I'm unable to add packages and Scala sources to any of the subprojects).

[image]

Comment: How about reading https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/intro_multi_project_builds.html and https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html? IJ will do the right thing automatically.

Comment: Thanks @Vampire (+1). So maybe the order here is: (1) Close the project in IJ, (2) Remove the `.idea` directory, (3) Rearrange the project directory structure the way I show up above, (4) Edit `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle` according to the Gradle docs, and (5) Re-import/open the project into IJ? Sound right, or am I missing/misunderstanding? Thanks again!

Comment: You don't need to close and delete IJ stuff. Just move and edit in IJ. If you enabled auto-import when opening the Gradle build, IJ will automatically catch up. If you didn't do, then either enable auto-import or manually press Refresh in the Gradle tool window.

Comment: Hmmm thanks again @Vampire (+1) but please see [my latest changes](https://github.com/hotmeatballsoup/intellij-scala-gradle-example/commit/151b8c4f0dbc914d7a55877b485e816e3bc254c5). I did what you suggested and (inside IJ) I deleted the root `src/` dir and created the client/shared/server directories. I then added a `build.gradle` to each of them like the docs suggest, and then included all of those subprojects in my root/parent `settings.gradle`.

Comment: But when I right-click on, say, `client/src/main/scala` and then click on `New` it won't let me create a new Scala class, which tells me something is wrong (please see the screenshot above). Any thoughts there? Thanks again enormously!

Comment: The directories are not marked as source roots, so you either did not sync (or do not have autosync on), or you didn't apply the scala plugin to the subprojects, either in their `build.gradle` or from the root project `build.gradle`.

Comment: Actually it seems to be the latter case, as your build.gradle files will be ignored. You put them inside `src/`, didn't you? Should be one level up to not be ignored.

Comment: @Vampire nope, check the GH repo, the `build.gradle` files are directly underneath the `client/`, `shared/` and `server/` directories, not inside their respective `src/` directories so I don't see how Gradle would be ignoring them...

Comment: Ah, right, had a lazy eye it seems. But well, I don't know why you set a bounty when I already told you what you made wrong, my sentence was still almost completely correct.

Comment: But would you have provided such a wonderful, thorough and succinct answer had I not posted the bounty?! I worship the Bounty Gods, and they take care of me *every* time!

Comment: Well, I had no time for a full answer at that time, hence a comment with the reason for you to self-fiddle. ;-)

Comment: Yet *another* miracle then! I prayed to the Bounty Gods, and they set forth a magnificent series of butterfly effects resulting with you having the time to heed my cries for help! Oh thank you Bounty Gods! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I already told you, you do not apply the scala plugin to the subprojects, so they are no scala projects and the directories are not recognized. You only apply the scala plugin to the root project, but that has nothing to do with the subprojects.

Either use

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'scala'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.8'
    }
}
```

to make all projects in the build scala projects, or

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'scala'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.8'
    }
}
```

to only do it for the subprojects, or do

```
apply plugin: 'scala'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.8'
}
```

in each individual build script or projects that you want to be scala projects, however you prefer.

If you did so, IJ also correctly recognizes the source folders correctly.

For the dependency part, just declare them like you want.

In your case add

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':shared')
}
```

to `client/build.gradle` and `server/build.gradle`, or do it from the root project build script for example like

```
configure([project(':server'), project(':client')]) {
    dependencies {
        compile project(':shared')
    }
}
```